# If $S$ is a vector space, then $S$ is a vector subspace of $S$

Tags: linear-algebra

$S$ is vector subspace of $S$ if $S$ is vector space, by hypothesis $S$ is vector space then $S$ is vector subspace of $S$.

But I prove it by contradiction, then $S$ is not vector subspace of $S$, but if $S$ is not vector subspace of $S$ then $S$ is not vector space but I have contraddiction, in fact by hypothesis $S$ is vector space, so $S$ is vector subspace of $S$.
Is it correct?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I am not sure whether it is correct, since it's a bit hard to follow your argument. Perhaps, you can clarify it by writing it in several distinct steps - or if you talk about different objects, use different notation.

Comment: One "S" more in this question and I'm sure the universe would have imploded...!

Comment: One definition of a vector subspace is a "subset which is a vector space (with the same zero vector and operations)". This definition is usually not the easiest one to work with (usually one uses what's written in xavierm02's answer), but in the case of this question it's the easiest one to use.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think, the implosion actually happened - not a very noticeable though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

- $S\subseteq S$
- $0\in S$
- $\forall u,v \in S, u+v \in S$
- $\forall c \in \Bbb K, \forall u \in S, cu \in S$

So yes, $S$ is a subspace of himself.

---

You might also know that for $T\subseteq S$,

$T$ is a subspace of $S$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $T$ is a vector space

So since $S \subseteq S$ and $S$ is a vector space, $S$ is a subspace of himself.$

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to show that if $S$ is a vector space, then $S$ is a subspace of $S$, then what you did is good. Your argument needs to go: $S$ is a vector space (by assumption), all elements of $S$ are elements of $S$, thus $S$ is a vector subspace of $S$. This is pretty trivial, though. In fact, $S$ and the empty set are often called the trivial subspaces of S and many times are just ignored.